# Get percentage from byte to gb python

Tags: python, math, percentage, filesize, calculation

I am working on a program that checks a folder size and then prints out the percentage of max amount used which is 50GB. The problem I am running into is if the data is only 1mb or a small number that is not a gb I do not get a accurate percentage. How can I improve my code to fix this problem.

```
import math, os

def get(fold):
        total_size = 0

        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(fold):
            for f in filenames:
                fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
                size = os.path.getsize(fp)
                total_size += size

        size_name = ("B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB")
        i = int(math.floor(math.log(total_size, 1024)))
        p = math.pow(1024, i)
        s = round(total_size / p, 2)

        return "%s %s" % (s, size_name[i])

per = 100*float(get(fold))/float(5e+10)
print(per)
```

Comment: What is your expected result? You can't get anything better than `0.00%` with only 2 digits after decimal. You may consider increasing the decimal digits in your `round` call.

Comment: @Selcuk well after I convert it. And go to calculate the percent my file is 500mb and it is returning 9 percent. When it should return 0.5.

Comment: Why would it return 0.5 and not 1%? In any case, you should add a sample case where it doesn't work as expected. It works fine for me.

Comment: @Selcuk Well 500MB is 0.5 percent of 50gb is it not?

Comment: No, it is not...

Comment: @Selcuk Ok sorry excuse my bad math been a long night... I just have one more question if the folder is 5gb it says the percent is 1 why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One place you're potentially undercounting is that you're adding up file sizes without accounting for block size.  On my system, for example, the allocation block size is 4096 bytes.  So if I 'echo 1 > test.txt', this 1 byte file takes up 4096 bytes.  We can rework the code to try to account for blocks:

```
import math
import os

SIZE_NAMES = ("B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB")

def get(fold):
    total_size = 0

    for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(fold):
        for f in filenames:
            fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            stat = os.stat(fp)
            size = stat.st_blksize * math.ceil(stat.st_size / float(stat.st_blksize))
            total_size += size

    i = int(math.floor(math.log(total_size, 1024)))
    p = math.pow(1024, i)
    s = round(total_size / p, 2)

    return "%s %s" % (s, SIZE_NAMES[i])
```

Although the `getsize()` undercount affects all files, percentage-wise, it affects smaller files more.  And, of course, directory nodes take up space too.  Also, this calculation has several problems:

```
per = 100*float(get(fold))/float(5e+10)
```

First, it fails as `fold()` returns a string like `'122.23 MB'` which `float()` doesn't like.  Second, it fails to account for the unit of the number which has been adjusted in the `float()` code but not unadjusted here.  Finally, it doesn't address the gigabyte vs. gibibyte issue (in a comment if nothing else.)  I.e. the space is reduced by powers of 1024 in the `fold()` code but divided by powers of 1000 here.  My rework:

```
number, unit = get(fold).split()  # "2.34 MB" -> ["2.34", "MB"]
number = float(number) * 1024 ** SIZE_NAMES.index(unit)  # 2.34 * 1024 ** 2
print("{0:%}".format(number / 500e9))  # percentage of 500GB
```

Comment: I get this error when I use your code? `AttributeError: 'nt.stat_result' object has no attribute 'st_blksize'`

Comment: @cdw100100, it works on Python 2 & 3 on my system so I guess it's an OS-specific thing as this is an os-specific interface.  I.e. my guess is you're on Windows?

Comment: @cdw100100, if you can't find a Windows-specific way to get the block size via Python, you can substitute a constant as the block size shouldn't  change from file to file within a directory.  If you can't find this value for Windows 10, you could use a constant of 4096 and adjust up or down the powers of 2 until a known folder measures the same for your code and the OS' own utilities.

Comment: I just want to make sure that the way I am calculating the percentage is correct though?

Comment: @cdw100100, my belief is there are several errors in how you calculate the percentage.  I've updated my answer with an explanation and code regarding this.

Comment: Thank you so much I am terrible when it comes to calculations with percentages!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing things a bit in your code; for example, your function `get()` returns a string but you try to cast it to a `float` later.

I suggest separating it a bit. First a function to format the size (I got some ideas form other stackoverflow questions):

```
SIZE_UNITS = ['', 'K', 'M', 'G', 'T']

def format_size(size_in_bytes):
    if size_in_bytes == 0:
        return '0.0 B'

    exp = math.floor(math.log(size_in_bytes, 1024))
    size = size_in_bytes / math.pow(1024, exp)
    return '{:.1f} {}B'.format(
        size,
        SIZE_UNITS[exp])
```

The you have a function to calculate the size of a directory and one for printing the info nicely:

```
def get_size_of_dir(dir_path):
    total_size = 0

    for dir_path, dir_list, file_list in os.walk(dir_path):
        for filename in file_list:
            f = os.path.join(dir_path, filename)
            size = os.path.getsize(f)
            total_size += size

    return total_size

def print_info(dir_path, capacity):
    total_size = get_size_of_dir(dir_path)
    percent = total_size * 100.0 / capacity

    print()
    print('Directory:     "{}"'.format(dir_path))
    print('capacity       {:>10s}'.format(format_size(capacity)))
    print('total_size     {:>10s}'.format(format_size(total_size)))
    print('percent used   {:8.1f} %'.format(percent))
```

Which on my machine looks like this:

```
# 1024**1 == > 1 KB
# 1024**2 == > 1 MB
# 1024**3 == > 1 GB
>>> capacity = 5 * 1024**3

>>> for folder in ('/home/ralf/Documents/', '/home/ralf/Downloads/'):
...     print_info(folder, capacity)

Directory:     "/home/ralf/Documents/"
capacity           5.0 GB
total_size       721.7 MB
percent used       14.1 %

Directory:     "/home/ralf/Downloads/"
capacity           5.0 GB
total_size         1.3 GB
percent used       25.7 %
```